# How can I add a custom attribute to Gutenberg core blocks?

Tags: block-editor

I'm trying to add a dropdown to Wordpress core blocks to select a data attribute that will be added to the front-end (e.g. data-attr="value-from-dropdown").

I think the solution is to add a custom attribute to the core blocks, set it in the back-end and pass it to the front-end, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to add a new attribute to a core block. This here is the closest I've gotten, but this just lets me create a dropdown, running props.setAttribute() inside doesn't work.

https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/extensibility/extending-blocks/#editor-blockedit

Is there anything I can do, or is the functionality just not there yet?

Comment: I've created a tutorial here : https://jeffreycarandang.com/extending-gutenberg-core-blocks-with-custom-attributes-and-controls/ . I hope this could help. Thanks!

Comment: @JeffreyCarandang that link gives a 404

Comment: @kanga It's all good now. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can add a custom attribute to any registered block by using the [`blocks.registerBlockType`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/filters/block-filters/#blocks-registerblocktype) filter.

```
/**
 * Filter the attributes for all blocks to add custom ones
 *
 * Name can be used to only add the new attribute to a certain block.
 *
 * @param settings
 * @param name
 * @returns {*}
 */
function addCustomAttributes( settings, name ) {
    if ( settings.attributes ) {

        settings.attributes.customAttribute = {
            type: 'string',
            default: ''
        };

        settings.attributes.anotherCustomAttribute = {
            type: 'boolean',
            default: false
        };
    }
    return settings;
}

addFilter( 'blocks.registerBlockType', 'namespace/filterBlockAttributes', addCustomAttributes );
```

Answer (score 3):

First inside the edit function declare a variable with your dropdown option -

```
const linkOptions = [
        { value: 'small', label: __( 'Small' ) },
        { value: 'normal', label: __( 'Normal' ) },
        { value: 'medium', label: __( 'Medium' ) },
        { value: 'large', label: __( 'Large' ) },
    ];
```

I'm assuming you will be showing the dropdown option in the Sidebar panel. Here's the code for panelbody and how to get the dropdown value -

```
<PanelBody>
  <SelectControl
    label={ __( 'Size' ) }
    value={ size }
    options={ linkOptions.map( ({ value, label }) => ( {
    value: value,
    label: label,
    } ) ) }
    onChange={ ( newSize ) => { setAttributes( { size: newSize } ) } }
   />
</PanelBody>
```

This will show a dropdown panel in the Inspector area, notice I'm using (ES6)Map function to iterate over the values and corresponding labels. Now, comes the RichText Component where you call the HTML nodes -

```
<RichText
      tagName={ 'span' }
      placeholder={ __( 'Enter Text' ) }
      value={ text }
      onChange={ (text) => setAttributes( { text: text } ) }
      formattingControls={ [ 'bold', 'italic', 'strikethrough' ] }
      className={`button-${size}`} /*ES6 Template Literals*/
      isSelected={ isSelected }
      keepPlaceholderOnFocus
/>
```

Notice, Depending upon the dropdown option. Button size gets attached to the HTML node classname. Now in the editor stylesheet, Add couple of css class and properties -

```
button-small
button-normal
button-medium
button-large
```

For the save function -

```
const save = ( props ) => {

    const {  size } = props.attributes;


    return (
        <div className={ `ubutton-${size}` }>

        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I edit a core block with this? From what I've seen, this only applies to creating a new block.

Comment: That's currently in "experimental phase". For more info check out this doc - https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/docs/extensibility/extending-blocks.md

Comment: That link is a 404. It's always best to link to a specific blob, rather than `master`, because `master` changes.